# How to cell wise large raster/stack in R?

Tags: raster, r

Now there are time series rasters `r1,r2,r3,...,r100`. I want to predict future values cell-wise and generate new rasters (i.e., `r101,102...`).
Fake code as follows:

```
#stack all raster
stk <- stack(r1,r2,r3,...,r100)
#convert stack to numeric， one column corresponding to one layer,
#rows coresponding to raster cells.
vals <- values(stk)
# apply function on each row (cells),predicted values saved to array
arr <- apply( vals,1, function)
#write to new Rasters
writeRaster(arr,'/r101.tif')
```

This method is available for small size stack because it read all data into memory in R. If the stack is large, are there other methods processing block by block on stacks/raster?

Comment: Please look at the help document for the `predict` function specific to the raster package. It is also documented in the package vigenett. You could also pass a custom function to `calc` or `overlay`.